# Cauchy criterion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

We know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$ coverge to 1.

I want use Cauchy criterion to show the series converges as an exercise. Is the following proof correct?

Given $\epsilon >0$, 
we want to show that we can find an $N$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n+1}^m \frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}\right| \le \epsilon
\end{align*} 
whenever $m> n > N$.

Let $N=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$ then if $m > n \ge N$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}\right| \le \dfrac{1}{n+1} \le \dfrac{1}{N+1} \le \epsilon.
\end{align*} 
Hence by the Cauchy criterion, the series is convergent.

Comment: Certainly $\le \epsilon$. You might want to say $\lt$, though of course $\le$ is perfectly correct. Good. Perhaps should make telescoping argument explicit. You know and I know why the collapse, but someone reading it might not.